# How to compute $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} dxdy$

Tags: calculus

How can I change the variable in $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} dxdy$$ to computer the value

I tried to let $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$

But I have no idea for next step

Can you give me some suggestion,thank you!!!

Comment: You have to figure out how those substitutions $u,v$ determine the new region of integration. The region in the $x$-$y$ plane is a square in the first quadrant. See how each line segment of the square is mapped into the $u$-$v$ plane. From there you will need to calculate the Jacobian.

Comment: @Chih Chia Chang see my answer and find out that you can get any value you want, and the reason for it.

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Comment: @Chih Chia Chang +1 for a good question. Late but not too late. After more than 3 years you should have made up your mind which answer you accept.

Answer (score 3):

The integral is divergent in the origin (x,y) = (0,0) and hence the expression simply makes no sense without additional prescriptions about how to circumvent the divergence.

We shall present one possible regularization and show that the so defined integral can assume any real value we want (including infinity).

To begin with, let us exclude the origin introducing two small positive parameters $\epsilon $ and $\delta$:

$$f(\epsilon ,\delta )=\int _{\epsilon }^1\int _{\delta }^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dydx$$

The integral is now well defined and the result is independent of the order of integration

$$\text{f1}=\frac{\delta  (\epsilon -1)}{(\delta +1) (\delta +\epsilon )}+\frac{1}{\epsilon +1}-\frac{1}{2}$$

We now want to let $\epsilon $ and $\delta$ go to zero.
There are many possibilities to do that.

1) sequential

First $\epsilon \to 0$, then $\delta \to 0$ gives $-\frac{1}{2}$

First $\delta \to 0$, then $\epsilon \to 0$ gives $+\frac{1}{2}$

Thus the result depends on the order.

2) Simultaneously, on a staight line $\delta =q \epsilon$

The limit $\epsilon \to 0$ is

$$f2 = \frac{1-q}{2 q+2}$$

which can assume, by an appropriate choice of q, any real value.
The choice q = 1 is normally called principal value and is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{-x}{(x+y)^2}\right)$$

Then you should easily find for the iterated integral

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dx \, dy
= -1/2$$

Note that switching the order of integration gives a value of $+1/2$ by antisymmetry of the integrand.

Comment: you show here that you can't swich the integrals. But can you explain my why theoreticly it goes wrong?

Comment: O no i'm sorry i tried to bookmark it and I accedently pushed on all the buttons

Comment: If you could edit you're question I can change it, im really sorry

Comment: I changed it, I'm sorry

Comment: OK -- thanks ...

Comment: You can't switch the integrals because Tonelli and Fubini theorems do not hold here.

Comment: The integrand is not nonnegative (as needed for Tonelli's theorem) and it is not absolutely integrable (as needed for Fubini's theorem).

Comment: Yes I thought so, but when i try to slove the absolutely integrand of this function I become a really long expression? Do you know an easy way to solve it?

Comment: Note that  $$\int_{[0,1]^2}|f| \geqslant \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_\delta ^1 \frac{|r \cos\theta - r\sin\theta|}{|r \cos\theta + r\sin\theta|^3}\, r\, dr\, d\theta = \int_\delta^1 \frac{dr}{r}\int_0^{\pi/2 }\frac{| \cos\theta - \sin\theta|}{| \cos\theta + \sin\theta|^3}\underset{\delta \to 0+}\longrightarrow + \infty$$

Comment: ... and the part that depends on $\theta$ is never $0$ in $0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: So the iterated integrals exist (but are unequal) because of lucky cancellation with an integrand that changes sign.

Comment: one more question about your comment, why u use delta and not 0?

Comment: Oh I got it already, thank you

Comment: I'm just being careful since the integrand is not Riemann integrable over that sector (it is unbounded at the origin) and I want to justify splitting the double integral (with respect to product measure) into two integrals, Splitting into two integrals is just using an iterated integral and this is valid when the integrand is Riemann integrable over a sector that excludes $(0,0)$.